# Mill: How to generate uberjar using publishVersion?

Tags: scala, build-tools, mill

Mill can generate (Uber)jar by `mill assembly`. Generated file is located at `out/assembly.dest/out.jar`.

How can I customize output filename instead of `out.jar`? I'd like to use value of `publishVersion` (I'm using [`mill-vcs-version`](https://github.com/lefou/mill-vcs-version)).

sbt can generate well-named uberjar.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the outcome by overriding the `assembly` target.

```scala
def assembly(): T[PathRef] = T {
  val dest = T.dest / s"${artifactName()}-${publishVersion()}-assembly.jar"
  os.copy(super.assembly().path, dest)
  PathRef(dest)
}
```

Instead of `artifactName`, you could also use `artifactId`, which would also contain the Scala version suffix and potential platform suffixes.

If you need those kind of customizations in multiple places, you should consider using a [trait module](https://mill-build.com/mill/Modules.html#_trait_modules).